# Loading requirejs/angularjs application within dojox/layout/ContentPane

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, requirejs

Our application is written using dojo 1.10. Within our application we have a need to display a 'form' loaded from an external domain source. To accomplish this we intend to use 'dojox/layout/ContentPane'.

The external form itself is actually also an HTML5 application using RequireJS/AngularJS. We don't have much scope to make changes to this application so any issues regarding its loading into a div in our application would need to be handled by a shim and/or dynamically modifying its scripts, to for example, ensure that angular modules were loaded from the cross domain source.

I found some mention on Stack Overflow and other sites regarding issues loading Dojo widgets within a RequireJS/Angular application but no clue as to how to handle our scenario. We are able to get HTML and scripts to load with small modifications to dojox ContentPane to enable the requireConfig.js file to load. However since our application is using dojo "require" and "define" already  requirejs won't start because of the following check:

```
if (typeof define !== 'undefined') {
    //If a define is already in play via another AMD loader,
    //do not overwrite.
    return;
}
```

Is there a way of overcoming this issue so that the RequireJS AMD loader can be used without modification? Unfortunately changing the forms implementation to work with (for instance dojos AMD loader) may not be an option.

Comment: In this particular case it really seems like you're trying to stretch a ContentPane out to behave like an iframe.  Admittedly this is what a lot of people try to do with `dojox/layout/ContentPane` but it is generally not a good idea.  ContentPanes are normally intended to display fragments of documents, not shove a complete Web page inside another with its own styles and framework that risk clashing with the parent application.

Comment: Thanks. I tend to agree this is stretching the ContentPane a bit far. This is something we are contracted to implement but we didn't discover the complexity of the embedded 'form' till recently.